# How i can set pagination to my html table using ajax with the asp.net asmx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using an ASP.Net page and Webservices.asmx webservice. I need to add pagination to my HTML table but I don't know how to include it. I have tried several ways but without success. I'd appreciate any help.

The aspx page code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("#btnShowData").click(function () {

        $('#todaywork').on('click', function () {
            var timeid = $('#View').html();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Todayworktime.asmx/Gettodaywork',
                data: { user: timeid },
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    var employeeTable = $('#tblEmployee tbody');

                    var employeehead = $('#tblEmployee thead');
                    employeeTable.empty();
                    employeehead.empty();
                    employeehead.append('<tr>' +

                        '<th>Username</th>' +
                        '<th>Date</th>' +
                        '<th>Total_Time</th>' +
                        '<th>Task</th>' +
                        '<th>Select</th>' +
                        '</tr > ');
                    $(data).each(function (index, emp) {

                        employeeTable.append('<tr><td>'
                            + emp.Username + '</td><td>' + emp.Date + '</td><td>' + emp.Total_Time
                            + '</td><td>' + emp.Task + '</td><td><button type="button" data-id="' + emp.Task + '" class="get_tsk" style="background-color:steelblue;color:white;border:none;">view</button></td></tr>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My asmx page code is

```
public class Todayworktime : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
    public void Gettodaywork(string user)
    {
        List<sessionlist> employeelist = new List<sessionlist>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Todaywork where Username='" + user + "' and Date='"+DateTime.Today+"'", con);
            // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                sessionlist employee = new sessionlist();
                employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                employee.Username = rdr["Username"].ToString();
                employee.Date = rdr["Date"].ToString();
                employee.Total_Time = rdr["Total_Time"].ToString();
                employee.Task = rdr["Task"].ToString();
                employeelist.Add(employee);
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employeelist));
    }
}
```

The Class I used :

```
public class sessionlist
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Total_Time { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried many ways but I don't get the result I'm expecting, so does anyone know how to apply pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass currentPageNo, PageSize via ajax to the asmx web method . In the method you shoould use a query like
`SELECT Fname, Lname FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary OFFSET @StartPage ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like are you already using jQuery. Why don't you use jQuery table and pagination plugins to implement the functionality.

Take a look at some plugin [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/12-amazing-jquery-tables/).

You can also take a look at the jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin which is free